# How to change option set field to use another (existing) option set?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

One field on Contact entity has 'option set' type. Now I want change field to use existing option set, but without re-creating field.
This option is currently disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done - once you've set a field up to use it's own option set, you can't change it to use a shared one instead, just as you can't change the field type or schema name after it's committed to the database.

If you've got a shared option set ready, it shouldn't be too big a deal to delete the field and re-create it with the shared option set.  You would most likely lose the data which was in this field previously, though.

If this is an issue, consider exporting the data before making the change and then importing it back in, though I'm not sure of the exact details of how this would work.

Comment: If losing data is an issue then create the new field, remove the old one from the form, make it not searchable. Then use workflows to copy values from field A > B, then delete the old field (and only if you really have to)

Comment: What AdamV said. Export/Import will not work, you will need to use workflows to update the field.